# How to disable the output in hook.io

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using hook.io programmatically for tiny application servers. On every connect and event it prints stuff, but I want only error outputs. Is there any way to silence the hook objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.**

Try using the *--silent* mode on the command line.

Like all hook.io options, you can also pass this into your hook constructor.

```
 new Hook({silent: true}
```